# Transform this matrix of distances into a more general one

Tags: matrices, transformation

I need to make the navigation and guidance of a vehicle (a quadcopter) in a platform. This platform can be seen like this:

[image]

where the blue dots are the center of each square, and the $x$ distances are all the same, and the $y$ distances are all the same.

I need the distance between each blue dot to the center (the blue dot of the $(2;2)$), but that distance depends on the $yaw$ angle. For example, if $yaw=0^\circ$, the situation is like this:

[image]

and the distances are:

$$d_{1;1} = (-d_x; -d_y)$$
$$d_{1;2} = (-d_x; 0)$$
$$d_{1;3} = (-d_x; d_y)$$

$$d_{2;1} = (0; -d_y)$$
$$d_{2;2} = (0; 0)$$
$$d_{2;3} = (0; d_y)$$

$$d_{3;1} = (d_x; -d_y)$$
$$d_{3;2} = (d_x; 0)$$
$$d_{3;3} = (d_x; d_y)$$

If the situation is with $yaw=180^\circ$:

[image]

the distances are the same but with the opposite sign, i.e,

$$d_{1;1} = (d_x; d_y)$$
$$d_{1;2} = (d_x; 0)$$
$$d_{1;3} = (d_x; -d_y)$$

$$d_{2;1} = (0; d_y)$$
$$d_{2;2} = (0; 0)$$
$$d_{2;3} = (0; -d_y)$$

$$d_{3;1} = (-d_x; d_y)$$
$$d_{3;2} = (-d_x; 0)$$
$$d_{3;3} = (-d_x; -d_y)$$

If $yaw=90^\circ$, the situation is like this:

[image]

and the distances (see the difference between $d_x$ and $d_y$) would be:

$$d_{1;1} = (-d_y; d_x)$$
$$d_{1;2} = (-d_y; 0)$$
$$d_{1;3} = (-d_y; d_x)$$

$$d_{2;1} = (0; -d_x)$$
$$d_{2;2} = (0; 0)$$
$$d_{2;3} = (0; d_x)$$

$$d_{3;1} = (d_y; -d_x)$$
$$d_{3;2} = (d_y; 0)$$
$$d_{3;3} = (d_y; d_x)$$

If $yaw = -90^\circ$:

[image]

the distances would be:

$$d_{1;1} = (d_y; d_x)$$
$$d_{1;2} = (d_y; 0)$$
$$d_{1;3} = (d_y; -d_x)$$

$$d_{2;1} = (0; d_x)$$
$$d_{2;2} = (0; 0)$$
$$d_{2;3} = (0; -d_x)$$

$$d_{3;1} = (-d_y; d_x)$$
$$d_{3;2} = (-d_y; 0)$$
$$d_{3;3} = (-d_y; -d_x)$$

I need to write a matrix that uses the information of the $yaw$ angle and returns the distances from each angle (not just 0, 90, -90 and 180, but also 1, 2, 3, ...)

I tried to write it but I couldn't find the solution.

Thank you very much. I really need this help

Edit: please note that the coordinate frame moves with the quadcopter, like in this image:

[image]

Edit 2: for example, if $yaw=45^\circ$, then the distance from $(3;3)$ to $(2;2)$ is $\sqrt{d_x^2+d_y^2}$ in $x$ and $0$ in $y$.

Comment: @evaristegd I didn't understand your question. I need to solve this for my Thesis.

Comment: I am sorry. I meant: is yaw an initialism?

Comment: My camera sees the floor and when it sees a predefined tag, it gives me the $yaw$ angle between by camera and the tag (is always fixed to the floor). I don't know if you call that an initialism, but the $yaw$ angle is given like I said in the main post. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: It looks like this isn't getting much attention. Try SciCompSE.

Comment: OK, thanks! But I think that this forum is more appropriate

Comment: How can I improve my question, @evaristegd?

Comment: I would suggest making it shorter and to the point. Another option would be offering a bounty. For more: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13083/how-to-get-a-question-answered

Comment: I offered a bounty. I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what's going on here. (One source of confusion was that what you call distances--a term usually reserved for scalar quantities---are actually pairs of scalars encoding distances in two directions, i.e., vectors. It would be less confusing to call these *displacements*.)

Comment: Also, the signs of the components of these displacements appear inconsistent, both with the orientation of the (moving) coordinate frame and with each other. For example, in the first diagram, the displacement from $(2, 2)$ to $(1, 1)$ is given as $(-d_x, -d_y)$, but in the coordinate frame defined by the quadcopter's orientation that displacement is $(d_x, d_y)$. In the $\textrm{yaw} = 90^\circ$ case, in the coordinate frame the displacement from $(2, 2)$ to $(1, 1)$ is given as $(-d_y, -d_x)$ but should be $(d_y, -d_x)$.

Comment: (Looking now at your Edit 2, it looks like the displacements you're after are not the displacements from $(2, 2)$ to a general point $(a, b)$, but rather the displacements from $(a, b)$ to $(2, 2)$, which are their negatives. (This convention seems backward to me, but) this resolves the issue in the $\textrm{yaw} = 0^\circ$ case I mentioned but leaves outstanding the problem in the $\textrm{yaw} = 90^\circ$ case (where the displacement from $(1, 1)$ to $(2, 2)$ should be $(-d_y, d_x)$).

Comment: Finally, in your Edit 2, where the yaw is $45^\circ$, the $y$-coordinate of the displacement will only be zero if $d_x = d_y$, which is not specified.

Comment: In the situacion yaw=$90^\circ$ from $(1,1)$ to $(2,2)$, imagine that you're on $(1,1)$. You have to move $-d_x$ in the $y$ and $-d_y$ in the $x$ to reach the $(2,2)$ position

Comment: In the yaw=$45^\circ$ situacion, the $y$-coordinate displacement will be zero when you're on $(3,3)$ or in $(1,1)$, because you just have to move forward (i.e, in the $x$ position)

Comment: In the $\textrm{yaw} = 90^\circ$ case: According to your diagram---in particular the orientations of the $x-$ and $y-$axes determined by the coordinate frame---to get from $(1, 1)$ to $(2, 2)$ you have to move a distance $d_y$ to right and a distance $d_x$ down. But, as your diagram indicates, downward is the positive $y$-direction, so the $y$-coordinate of the displacement is $d_y$, not $-d_y$ as claimed.

Comment: In the $\textrm{yaw} = 45^\circ$ case: Like you claim if $d_x = d_y$ then it's true that the $y$-coordinate of the displacement is zero. But if $d_x \neq d_y$, then at, say, $(3, 3)$ the quadcopter is not facing directly at $(2, 2)$ so the $y$-coordinate cannot be zero. (Try drawing the layout of the dots when one of $d_x, d_y$ is much larger than the other.)

Comment: In the yaw=$90^\circ$ case: you're right.

In the yaw=$45^\circ$ case: you're right. I can make $d_x = d_y$, but it would be great if they could be different.

Answer (score 1):

If the $(\textrm{row} ; \textrm{column})$ label of the reference point is $(a_0; b_0)$ (in our case this is $(2; 2)$), then with respect to the standard basis (not the one depending on the yaw of the quadcopter) the displacement of that point from the one with the label $(a; b)$ is $${\bf s} := (d_x(a_0 - a), d_y(b_0 - b)) .$$ The problem is writing this displacement with respect to the coordinate frame basis defined by the quadcopter's current orientation.

Let $\theta$ denote the yaw of the quadcopter. As in the question statement we declare that the facing north is $\theta = 0$ and that increasing yaw correspondings to anticlockwise rotation. Then, by definition, the coordinate frame basis (written in terms of the standard basis) is
$$({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = ((-\sin \theta, \cos \theta), (-\cos \theta, -\sin \theta)) .$$
[Since this basis is orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection), the representation of the displacement vector ${\bf s}$ with respect to this basis is $$({\bf s} \cdot {\bf x}, {\bf s} \cdot {\bf y}) .$$
For example, the first component is
$$
{\bf s} \cdot {\bf x}
= (d_x(a_0 - a), d_y(b_0 - b)) \cdot (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta)
= d_x(a - a_0) \sin \theta - d_y(b - b_0) \cos \theta .
$$
Notice that this formula shows that using the convention $(a_0; b_0) = (0; 0)$ would be especially convenient, as the formula then simplifies to
$$
{\bf s} \cdot {\bf x}
= d_x a \sin \theta - d_y b \cos \theta .
$$

---

**Example** For the setup in the question, we carry out part of the computation in the case that the spacing is given by $d_x = 1, d_y = 2$ and the yaw is $20^\circ$. We find the components of displacement vector from the point with row/column label $(a; b) = (1; 1)$ to the reference point, which has label $(a_0; b_0) = (2; 2)$.

Substituting in the formula for $\bf s$ gives that the displacement vector (with respect to the standard basis) is ${\bf s} = (1, 2)$. The coordinate frame basis (written with respect to the standard basis) is $({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = ((-\sin 20^\circ, \cos 20^\circ), (-\cos 20^\circ, -\sin 20^\circ))$, so, for example, the component of $\bf s$ in the $\bf x$-direction is
$${\bf s} \cdot {\bf x} = (1, 2) \cdot (-\sin 30^\circ, \cos 30^\circ) = -\sin 20^\circ + 2 \cos 20^\circ \approx 1.53736 .$$
The computation for the component in the ${\bf y}$-direction is similar.

Comment: the position of the element $(2,2)$ of the matrix is $(0;0)$ always. So, $(a_0, b_0) = (0,0)$, isn't it? In that case, what is difference between $(a,b)$ and $(d_x, d_y)$? The $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, etc. refer to the element number in the convention (row,column), as specified in the first image

Comment: I have followed your convention in using a semicolon $;$ when writing a pair that denotes row and column entry. But of course one could always choose to index the rows and columns in such a way that the reference point is $(0; 0)$ (making the index values of the rows and columns in your original diagram run from $-1$ to $1$)---I've adjusted the wording of my answer to emphasize this.

Comment: The pair $(a; b)$ specifies the row and column of the target point; the parameters $d_x, d_y$ are just the distances fixed in your question.

Comment: It seems that some of your original confusion was conflating the roles of a label $(a; b)$ of a position in a particular row and column and the notation $(u, v)$ for a point. (NB in my answer we never needed the latter, just the notation $(u, v)$ for a vector between two points.) In particular, this explains the original confusion in the $\textrm{yaw} = 45^\circ$ case.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying. For example, using that equation, which would be the result for yaw=20?

Comment: I've added to my answer a worked example for $\textrm{yaw} = 20^\circ$ and simple choices of $d_x, d_y$, and $(a; b)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but since it will take some space, writing it here.

I think you are asking about "directed distance" or a "vector" from the point $(2,2)$ to each of the other points.  Depending on what your coordinate axes are, the vectors each undergo a rotation.

I am not sure why, in the canonical form (your first example) you've defined $x$ to be up and $y$ to the left.  That's okay, as long as you are consistent.  But then, why is $d_{1,1}=-(d_y,d_x)$?  Are you defining the directed distance from $(1,1)$ to $(2,2)$.  Seems that $(2,2)$ is the origin of your coordinate system.  We usually define vectors or directed distances from the origin to another point.  In any case, once you settle on a meaningful coordinate system, any rotation in the axes can be coded (calculated) by multiplying each vector by a rotation matrix.

$$R=\begin{pmatrix} \phantom{-} \cos \varphi& \sin \varphi\\ -\sin\varphi & \cos \varphi \end{pmatrix},$$ being careful to define $\phi$ appropriately as the angle of rotation from one of the coordinate axes.  Depending on whether you are defining the rotation of the axes, or the rotation of the vector (and how you define all of the above), that minus sign might be better placed with the other $\sin \phi$.  A simple way to check if you have it correct is to compute the resulting vectors for some special case, for example $\varphi=30^\circ.$

Comment: The displacement is from any element of the matrix to $(2,2)$. So, with yaw=$0^\circ$, $d_{{(1,1)}\rightarrow{(2,2)}}=(-d_x,-d_y)$ because if you're on $(1,1)$ you have to move $-d_x$ in $x$ and $-d_y$ in $y$

Comment: Okay.  Fine.  Somebody suggested to post your question on the CS SE site.  I suggest looking in a robotics or mechanics textbook.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple pythagorean formula for the distance of a lattice point $(j,k)$ from the center $(j_c, k_c)$ of the rectangular lattice, namely
$$d(j,k)=\sqrt{(j-j_c)^2 dx^2 +(k-k_c)^2 dy^2}\ .$$
In the case at hand $(j_c,k_c)=(2,2)$, but in a general case $j_c$, $k_c$ might be half integer numbers.

One does not have to deal with the "yaw angles" or the (unknown) polar angles of the displacement vectors in question. But maybe your problem is completely different, and you have not yet clearly formulated it.

Comment: OK, but in that formula the displacements $d_x$ and $d_y$ will change with the yaw angle. For example, if yaw=0, then $d_x=d_y=1$ and if yaw=45, then $d_x=\sqrt{2}, d_y=0$

Comment: Christian, when OP wrote "distance" in the original formulation of the question, he meant "displacement", I believe.

Comment: Yes, Travis. Thanks